# How to use the camera with images?

Tags: android, background, camera

I want to make an application that contains an image and the background you can use the device camera. I know how to launch the camera but not how put  the image forward. An example would be this application:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kat.police.photosuit.montage

Anybody know any tutorial explaining how to do it or some code?

I have searched but can not find perhaps because my English is not very good. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/

and use this layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.javacodegeeks.androidsurfaceviewexample.AndroidSurfaceviewExample" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/police"
        android:layout_above="@id/capture"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="captureImage"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Capture"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

In your surfaceCreated method you need to do something like this:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getPreviewSizes();

// You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
// Example Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);
Camera.Size previewSize = // .... select one of previewSizes here

parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

Comment: It look good, but it give me an error. This:
04-29 15:45:49.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15654): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
04-29 15:45:49.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15654):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
04-29 15:45:49.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15654):  at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1876)
04-29 15:45:49.045: E/AndroidRuntime(15654):  at com.javacodegeeks.androidsurfaceviewexample.AndroidSurfaceviewExample.surfaceCreated(AndroidSurfaceviewExample.java:116)

Comment: not all devices support arbitrary preview sizes, get the preview size from the camera

Comment: Thank you Lesther Vega. Anyway I'll have to figure out how to save the resulting image, if you know or you know any tutorial I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your solution should not be overlapping images. I think that what your are looking for is more complex. You should have both images and then program an algorithm to mix them up and show just one image on your imageView.